# Had rather; grammar explanation

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, phrase-meaning, archaicisms

In [the *Iliad* (translated by Samuel Butler)](http://classics.mit.edu/Homer/iliad.1.i.html) I have lit upon the phrase *had rather* here:

> But the son of Peleus again began railing at the son of Atreus, for he was still in a rage. "Wine-bibber," he cried, "with the face of a dog and the heart of a hind, you never dare to go out with the host in fight, nor yet with our chosen men in ambuscade. You shun this as you do death itself. You **had rather** go round and rob his prizes from any man who contradicts you. You devour your people, for you are king over a feeble folk; otherwise, son of Atreus, henceforward you would insult no man

Now, of course, to the modern English speaker *would rather* is the more familiar phrase. I have looked at the other “had rather questions” on this site but none of the answers has been satisfactory.

Thus my questions are; Is it simply an unlettered or vulgar form of *would rather* or is there grammar behind it, and if so, where can I read further on the topic? None of the answers seems to explain whether *had rather* is grammatical and if so why; is it an archaic version of *would rather*?

Comment: Vulgur, no. Very high-toned. RP subjunctive, maybe.

Comment: Google ngram shows "would rather" is more used than "had rather", though the difference was less in the early 1800s. Note that both contract to "you'd rather.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*[The American Journal of Philology](https://www.jstor.org/stable/287026#metadata_info_tab_contents)* has an article entitled ***On the Origin of “Had Rather Go” and Analogous or Apparently Analogous Locutions***. It says:

> Of the verb *have*, Dr. Johnson, in his *Dictionary*, gives, as the
> seventeenth definition, “***to wish, to desire, in a lax sense***,” and
> adds, by way of exemplification, the familiar Biblical passage:
>
> - I ***had rather*** be a doorkeeper (Ps. 84:10).

*[That's KJV, so think 16th century.* Which makes me think of Shakespeare. He used it quite often:
e.g.

> I ***had rather*** hear my dog bark at a crow, than a man swear he loves me. (*[Much Ado About Nothing](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/much_ado/full.html)*)*]*

The article from *The American Journal of Philology* continues:

> A still more disparaging opinion, perhaps a maturer, he [Dr. Johnson] records
> under the adverb ***rather***, where, as introductory to a sentence containing the phrase
>
> - He ***had rather*** mankind should adore him,
>
> after premising “to have rather,” defined by “***to desire in preference***,” he remarks:
>
> > This is, I think, a barbarous expression, of
> > late intrusion into our language, for which it is better to say *will rather*.

It's a very interesting read, I think you will find all your answers there. The article quotes grammarians who agree that *had rather* is *strangely ungrammatical*:

> ***Had*** is an auxiliary verb, and so cannot be coupled with an infinitive.
> Thus argued Thomas Sheridan, in 1784:
>
> > *‘I had rather’*. This
> > phrase is strangely ungrammatical. *Rather* means ‘ more willingly.’
>
> The adverb *rather* is expressive of an act of the will,
> and, therefore, should be joined to the verb *to will*, and not to the
> auxiliary *to have*. Instead of ‘I had rather’ it should be ‘I would rather’.
>
> Bishop Lowth remarks, in his *Short Introduction to English
> Grammar*:
>
> > It has been very rightly observed, that the verb
> > *had*, in the common phrase ‘I had rather’ is not properly used
> > either as an active or as an auxiliary verb; that, ***being in the past
> > time, it cannot, in this case, be properly expressive of time present*** ;
> > and that it is ***by no means reducible to any grammatical construction***. In truth, *it seems to have arisen from a mere mistake, in
> > resolving the familiar and ambiguous abbreviation **‘I'd rather’** into
> > **‘I had rather’** instead of **‘I would rather’*** which latter is the
> > regular, analogous [read analogical], and proper expression.

I don't want this post to become too long but I will still add what the article says about Merriam-Webster's opinion about the matter

> Later grammarians and lexicographers, in general, accept this
> solution; and the editors of Webster’s Dictionary go so far as
> confidently to pronounce *had rather, had as lief*, and *had better* to have been ‘**originally, mere blundering interpretations of the abbreviated form of *would* as in *I’d rather***’.

Despite all that, the expression ***had rather*** is considered idiomatic, though listed as *[archaic/literary](https://www.google.com/search?q=had%20rather%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsazAnN-1zDfAVgl7V9Q70X8-xQOSg%3A1664784441449&source=hp&ei=OZg6Y57uGMuAhbIPp5uTkAc&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYzqmSf_goKYRs-2cyuPBG7iY85gC-wev&oq=had%20rather%20mean&gs_lcp=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&sclient=gws-wiz)* in dictionaries. This question about the [usage of *had rather*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128558/using-i-had-rather-instead-of-i-would-rather) may also help.

Comment: A fascinating story of how the barbarous can become acceptable and then slip into the archaic/literary register.

Comment: _Had_ has too many jobs already. Better to use a modal, since _rather_ is comparative.

Answer (score 2):

The verbs in speech by Peleus’ son are all in the continuous present because that was the situation in the past, and it continues now. If the speaker was alive today, instead of saying,” You would rather” he would have said, “You would **have** rather” or the Greek equivalent. “You had rather” meant just that.
He can’t accuse him of doing that, but he suspects that is what the son of Atreus would have liked to do. Never would I have argued Greek translation with Samuel Butler.